# Ler informação de excel em forma de matriz com python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, python-2.7

Estou a usar o Python 2.7 para ler valores de um documento do Excel. Quando tenho apenas uma linha de valores com respectivo header consigo ler, fazendo

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("Resultados.xlsx")
Nod=49 #numero de celulas com dados
sheet1=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Primeira')
ph_value=[]
for a in range(1,Nod+1): 
    ph_value.append(sheet1.cell(row=3, column=a).value)
```

No entanto tenho folhas do Excel que em vez de ter uma linha de dados com várias colunas como o exemplo anterior, tenho várias linhas com várias colunas, ou seja uma matriz. Além dos valores preciso associar os respectivos headers de linha e coluna e só consigo fazer para uma linha, da seguinte forma:

```
sheet6=wb.get_sheet_by_name('PTran_A')
p_t_a_value=[]
for a in range(2,Nod+1): 
    p_t_a_value.append(sheet6.cell(row=3, column=a).value)

p=[]
ind_p=[]
```

Ciclo que tira todos os valores da linha e só conta os que têm valor, as células preenchidas e os índices respectivos, eliminando as que estão em branco. Esses índices correspondem ao que ocorre em cada header/cabeçalho:

```
for b in range(0,len(p_t_a_value)):
    if (p_t_a_value[b]!=None):
        p.append(p_t_a_value[b])
        ind_p.append(b)
```

Como é que posso tirar os valores para todas as linhas e colunas, podendo ter os valores e índices como fiz para uma só linha?

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a documentação, você também pode navegar nas linhas/colunas através de números (índices).

Sugiro um loop dentro do outro:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='large_file.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['big_data'] # ws agora é uma IterableWorksheet

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html